# How do I make a waterfall chart with error bars?

Tags: excel

Is there a way to make a waterfall chart in Excel with vertical error bars?

The built-in Waterfall chart function doesn't seem to allow error bars to be added.

To describe in words what I want to visualize: I want to show what creates the difference between the beginning and ending value. I have a distribution of possibilities for each variable's contribution to the difference between the beginning and ending values. I want to display the relative confidence for each variable compared to the other variables.

Example below, for Var1, there would be a vertical line through the first orange bar, the top of the line would go to 38 on the y-axis, and the bottom of the vertical line would go to 33 on the y-axis. Preferably, the error bars would have a horizontal bar on the end to denote where the confidence interval ends.

Thank you!

[image: Waterfall Example Table]
[image: Waterfall Example Chart]

Comment: Try [John Peltier](https://peltiertech.com/excel-waterfall-charts-bridge-charts/)s site. My first stop for all chart related info.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Unfortunately, this doesn't show how to add confidence intervals. Useful for creating a basic waterfall chart, though!